# Google reCAPTCHA Validation Issue (accepts anything including blank)

Tags: asp-classic, captcha, recaptcha

I'm attempting to implement Google's reCAPTCHA on a Classic ASP site and am attempting to follow the guidelines outline here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/asp

Following the instructions on that page, I've added this code to the top of the page that contains the form:

```
 <%
 recaptcha_challenge_field  = Request("recaptcha_challenge_field")
 recaptcha_response_field   = Request("recaptcha_response_field")
 recaptcha_public_key       = "<font color=red>your_public_key</font>" ' your public key
 recaptcha_private_key      = "<font color=red>your_private_key</font>" ' your private key
 ' returns the HTML for the widget
 function recaptcha_challenge_writer()
 recaptcha_challenge_writer = _
 "<script type=""text/javascript"">" & _
 "var RecaptchaOptions = {" & _
 "   theme : 'red'," & _
 "   tabindex : 0" & _
 "};" & _
 "</script>" & _
 "<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=" & recaptcha_public_key & """></script>" & _
 "<noscript>" & _
   "<iframe src=""http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=" & recaptcha_public_key & """ frameborder=""1""></iframe><br>" & _
     "<textarea name=""recaptcha_challenge_field"" rows=""3""cols=""40""></textarea>" & _
     "<input type=""hidden"" name=""recaptcha_response_field""value=""manual_challenge"">" & _
 "</noscript>"
 end function
 ' returns "" if correct, otherwise it returns the error response
 function recaptcha_confirm(rechallenge,reresponse)
 Dim VarString
 VarString = _
         "privatekey=" & recaptcha_private_key & _
         "&remoteip=" & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & _
         "&challenge=" & rechallenge & _
         "&response=" & reresponse
 Dim objXmlHttp
 Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 objXmlHttp.open "POST", "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", False
 objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 objXmlHttp.send VarString
 Dim ResponseString
 ResponseString = split(objXmlHttp.responseText, vblf)
 Set objXmlHttp = Nothing
 if ResponseString(0) = "true" then
   'They answered correctly
    recaptcha_confirm = ""
 else
   'They answered incorrectly
    recaptcha_confirm = ResponseString(1)
 end if
 end function
 server_response = ""
 newCaptcha = True
 if (recaptcha_challenge_field <> "" or recaptcha_response_field <> "") then
   server_response = recaptcha_confirm(recaptcha_challenge_field, recaptcha_response_field)
   newCaptcha = False  
 end if
```

%>

Also per that page, I've added this code to the form itself to generate the reCAPTCHA widget:

```
 <% if server_response <> "" or newCaptcha then %>

    <% if newCaptcha = False then %>

      <!-- An error occurred -->
      Wrong!

    <% end if %>

      <%=recaptcha_challenge_writer()%>

  <% else %>

    <!-- The solution was correct -->
    Correct!

  <%end if%>
```

I can get the CAPTCHA to display properly, but it isn't verifying - it will accept any answer including being left blank. I believe some of the code needs to be added to my script that actually handles the data, but am not sure which code or where to put it.

I've tried moving portions of the above code that appear to be for validation purposes to the script that processes the responses and generates an e-mail, but have had no luck there either.

The for page can be viewed here:
http://www.onlyproforma.com/mktimg/landingPage_ResultsFirst4_CAPTCHA.asp

I am aware there are other options, but I would like to get this one working if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to implement recaptcha in Classic ASP. Please share your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the code previously references in the provided link.

Comment: Have you replaced the recaptcha_public_key and recaptcha_private_key with the actual keys generated? That is the first step. After that you'll need to fix the forms. The line <form action="recaptcha.asp" method="post"> of your code is within another form. There should be only one form and the second bit of your code  <% if server_response <> "" or newCaptcha then %> etc. should be added to the page where the form is posted. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I've placed the keys in the appropriate places or else I don't believe the CAPTCHA itself would show up. I will try your other suggestions shortly.

Comment: I believe the other elements of code are in the locations you describe.

Comment: So the second part of your code is within L_Landing_actionJCR.asp, right? In that case you'll need to debug there by checking the values of the variables.

Comment: After the form is submitted, if you just use  if server_response <> "" then <your code to handle error>, it should do the trick

Comment: Thank you. I have this code in the form itself, is that not where it should go?

    <% if server_response <> "" or newCaptcha then %>

    <% if newCaptcha = False then %>

      <!-- An error occurred -->
      Wrong!

    <% end if %>

    <!-- Generating the form -->

      <%=recaptcha_challenge_writer()%>


  <% else %>

    <!-- The solution was correct -->
    Correct!

  <%end if%>

Comment: No, your form is being posted to L_Landing_actionJCR.asp. So this bit of the code will go there as the values will be set after the form is posted.

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to get it. Please look at L_Landing_actionJCR.asp now. I was thinking if the CAPTCHA does not check out, it would display the "Wrong", which it does, but if it's OK,it would run the script that send the e-mail. Except what I get is that it says wrong every time.

Comment: I cannot look at the ASP code in the browser as it is on server side. I implemented it in ASP and I didn't need the newcaptcha variable. Please see the answer for a revised code snippet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue especially with the NEW reCAPTCHA tick functionality. If you look at the   reCAPTCHA admin site which gives you your public and private (secret) keys, you'll see that the server side integration URL to verify, is different from the code above. In the code above, the verify URL is _http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify whereas the verify URL supplied by the reCAPTCHA admin page is _https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. Very different.

Also, the parameters required are different. In the above code, there is a call for Request("recaptcha_challenge_field") and Request("recaptcha_response_field"). Yet the new reCAPTCHA verify only requires the response field. But even that has changed! It is now request.form("g-recaptcha-response").

Granted, the code that you are using above comes straight from Google themselves (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/asp). But it appears that this code is outdated, especially if you consider that it is filed in a directory called OLD.

So this is what worked for me!

```
Dim recaptcha_secret
recaptcha_secret = "your secret code"

Dim sendstring
sendstring = _
   "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?" & _ 
   "secret=" & recaptcha_secret & _
   "&response=" & request.form("g-recaptcha-response")

Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "GET", sendstring , false

objXML.Send()
```

The code below reads the response from Google. The reply comes back as a JSON object, but I cannot read or process the JSON response on the server-side and I could not find an easy method.

So the workaround was to search for the string 'true'. If it returned TRUE (positive) then the reCAPTCHA was confirmed. If it does not return TRUE, then the response is essentially
FALSE and the reCAPTCHA was not submitted correctly.

It is ugly but it works:

```
if instr(objXML.responseText,"true") then
        response.redirect "to an appropriate page"           
    else
        response.redirect "to an appropriate page"           
end if
```

Maybe there is a neater way to read the Google reply, but I have tested it and it works for me.

The full code then would look like this:

```
<%
Dim recaptcha_secret
recaptcha_secret = "your secret code"

Dim sendstring
sendstring = _
   "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?" & _ 
   "secret=" & recaptcha_secret & _
   "&response=" & request.form("g-recaptcha-response")

Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "GET", sendstring , false

objXML.Send()

if instr(objXML.responseText,"true") then
        response.redirect "to an appropriate page"           
    else
        response.redirect "to an appropriate page"           
end if
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will go in the page where the form is posted. i.e. in your case L_Landing_actionJCR.asp

```
<% if server_response <> "" then %>
  Wrong!
<% else %>
  Correct!
<% else %>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work. I'm in over my head and will look into other options. I do appreciate your help though.